# JQuery class selector isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to select an element based on its class (using $(".class")) and I'm having an issue, and I'm not sure why it's happening.

First off, the element is an image. It gets created when a function is executed by:

```
$("#container").append("<img class='removeIcon' src='images/remove.png' remove='"+$(this).val()+"' />");
```

This works as it should. The image is added when the function is fired, even multiple times. And the value of each is what it's meant to be, it's all good. The element is fine.

What isn't working...

```
$(".removeIcon").click(function() {
    alert();
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

I'm not sure if it's not working because the image is added later, or maybe I'm doing something wrong? But I whenever I click any of the images with that class, there's no alert dialog, and no console log.

I've typed, into console, $(".removeIcon"); - and it shows all of the images with that class, so I don't understand what's wrong. Can you not have a click even on a class selector?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use the jQuery on() method

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your code only works for existing `.removeIcon` elements.

if you do add dynamic elements, try use [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$("#container").on('click', '.removeIcon', function() {
    alert();
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

which binds `click` event on all `.removeIcon` elements inside `#container`
 (including dynamic added elements)

Comment: Well a few word of explanation will be better, so adding it. When you add dynamic element, they do not "retrigger" the document onload call, hence normally call like you do not get executed. This is where `on` is useful.

Comment: I would also mention [Event Delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), not just `.on` since it involves dynamically created elements.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks! I'll accept the answer in a few minutes when SO lets me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the problem is that it is being added later, so you have to delegate with:

```
$("#container").on('click', '.removeIcon', function() {
    alert();
    console.log("Clicked!");
});
```

So, the event will be asigned to the **container** but will act on **.removeIcon** items.

For more info check jQuery's [on function](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

**click()** function doesn't work with dynamically loaded data. 
You have to capture click event by **DOM** or by making **onclick** function

by DOM

`$("#container").on('click', '.removeIcon', function() {
    console.log("click");
});`

OR onclick function

```
$("#container").append("<img class='removeIcon' onclick="somefunctionInJS()" src='images/remove.png' remove='"+$(this).val()+"' />");
```